# C++ Pointer to member function, member

Tags: c++, function, pointers, member

I want to have a member that is a pointer to member function. Then I can set this pointer to point at one of the other member functions and use it to call the function I really want. Essentially I have different ways to implement a function and I want to set a pointer to call the appropriate one. Also the class is a template class.

I can't find a way call the function via the function pointer. 
For example:

```
template <typename T> class C
{
public:
    typedef void(C<T>::*Cfunc)(int);
    Cfunc cf;
    void p1(int i) {
    }
    C (int i)
    {
        cf = &C<T>::p1;
    }
};
int main ()
{
C<int> Try1(1);
(Try1.*C<int>::cf)(10);
 return 0;
}
```

I get the error:

```
tc.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
tc.cpp:5:11: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘C<int>::cf’
     Cfunc cf;
           ^
tc.cpp:16:16: error: from this location
 (Try1.*C<int>::cf)(10);
```

Comment: Do you really need a pointer to member variable? Between std::function and lambdas there's rarely any need.

Comment: I don't know how to solve my problem with std::function or lambdas. What I want is to be able to set at construction which of the set of implementations I want to use. I may also like to be able to dynamically change this during the life of the object by changing the pointer. So from my example sometimes cf points to p1 and sometimes it would point to an implementation p2. I don't want the trouble or overhead of having to have an if-then-else at the point of call.

Answer (score 7):

Your pointer to member function is not a static variable and therefore you need an instance of `C` to access it

```
int main()
{
  C<int> Try1(1);
  (Try1.*Try1.cf)(10);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. I didn't understand I had to have Try1 twice.

Comment: @KevinD You could avoid the `Try1` twice by having declaring `void wrap() { return (this->*cf)(10); }`  inside C.  The point is that you are using Try1 twice - once to get hold of the ptmf, once to *call* the function.  (And in the general case, those objects are often not the same).